# Applying cardinality for multiple columns in Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to apply Jolt for below data

**input**:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "500",
    "code": "abc",
    "date": "2020-10-10",
    "category": 1,
    "amount": 100,
    "result": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "500",
    "code": "abc",
    "date": "2020-10-10",
    "category": 2,
    "amount": 200,
    "result": 1
  }
]
```

**jolt used**:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "@(1,id).id",
        "code": "@(1,id).code",
        "date": "@(1,id).group1.date",
        "category": "@(1,id).group1.group2[&1].category"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

**current output**:

```json
{
  "id": "500",
  "code": [
    "abc",
    "abc"
  ],
  "group1": {
    "date": [
      "2020-10-10",
      "2020-10-10"
    ],
    "group2": [
      {
        "category": 1
      },
      {
        "category": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**expected**:

```json
{
  "id": "500",
  "code": "abc",
  "group1": {
    "date": "2020-10-10",
    "group2": [
      {
        "category": 1
      },
      {
        "category": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If i keep column of code & date in cardinality, it's fine. But in my use case, there are multiple such columns to be added. Are there any better ways to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add each *added node* and use **`"*"`** wildcard to represent the ***rest*** of the attributes within the **cardinality** transformation such as

```json
{
  "operation": "cardinality",
  "spec": {
    "*": {
      "*": "ONE",
      "group1": {
        "*": "ONE",
        "group2": "MANY"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where **`"group2": "MANY"`** will make **group2** to be excepted for extracting only the first element of the respective list.

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ :

[image]

Comment: Yes, it did work. Can you suggest any other sources where I can learn more about jolt?

Comment: Hi @Raviteja . You can check out [Releases](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/releases) and [Github link](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt)